# Redux-Thunk Chaining Actions, getting a "dispatch(...) then is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In order for me to set the Composition, I have to get the Output object first.
I'm trying to copy the examples and I feel like I'm copying the syntax correctly but I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function

Actions.js

```
export function setComposition(composition) {
  return { type: types.SET_COMPOSITION, composition };
}

export function setOutputs(outputs) {
  return { type: types.SET_OUTPUTS, outputs };
}

export function setOutputsAndComposition(outputs) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    return dispatch(setOutputs(outputs)).then(() =>  // ERROR HERE
      dispatch(setComposition(getState().Data.OutputObj))
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: Ideally I would love to just create a function that just does this:

```
export function setOutputsAndComposition(outputs) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(setOutputs(outputs)).then(() =>
    dispatch(setComposition(getState().Data.OutputObj))
    );
  }
}
```

But somewhere I'm obviously not doing the syntax correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setOutputs()` is returning a plain action object, and thus is not a thunk that returns a promise.  So, chaining `dispatch(setOutputs(outputs)).then()` won't work.

If you just want to dispatch another action right after the `setOutputs()` dispatch is complete, you only need to put them right after each other:

```
dispatch(setOutputs(outputs));
dispatch(setComposition(getState().Data.OutputObj));
```

Comment: if i wanted ".then()" to work, what would my setOutputs function have to return?

Comment: As I said, it would need to be another thunk function, and it would need to return a promise.

Comment: @markerikson:   Do you mean dispatch in thunk works like yield in saga . I was of the view that suppose if you want some action to dispatch after another action - we need to use **.then** to be sure that first action has returned .

Comment: You're mixing up two different things. The `dispatch` argument in a thunk is the exact `store.dispatch` method from the Redux store. `yield` is a JS keyword for pausing a saga and passing a value to the iterator.  The Redux-Saga API allows you to dispatch by using the `put()` effect, like `yield put({type: "increment"})`.

Comment: @markerikson : I got your point but when you mentioned above that you need to put  dispatch right after another dispatch when 2 actions need to be dispatched , I wanted to know if the second dispatch will wait for the first one to return and not start execution if the first dispatch is taking time to return. I have a use case where I want to dispatch 2 actions successively but the second one should start only after first one has returned and using **.then** gives the error

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setOutputs()` as a custom middleware. In this case I'm using it as a `Promise` instead:

```
export function setComposition(composition) {
  return { type: types.SET_COMPOSITION, composition };
}

export function setOutputs(outputs, dispatch) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dispatch({type: types.SET_OUTPUTS, outputs});
    resolve();
  });
}

export function setOutputsAndComposition(outputs) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    return setOutputs(outputs, dispatch).then(() =>  // NO ERROR HERE ANYMORE ^_^
      dispatch(setComposition(getState().Data.OutputObj))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative approach.  checking it out

Comment: Seems like this approach is not feasible, it results in another error - `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` It suggests you must use middleware, like `redux-thunk` for such types of actions